# Pull Voicemail Transcript from HTML Email (Zapier)

Tags: javascript, python, html, zapier

I'm using Google Voice to transcribe voicemail into text which I receive in an email notification. I stripped the html tags from the email and am left with the text below:

```
<!-- div, p, a, li, td {} .links-date a {color:#000000; text-decoration:none} .links-footer a {color:#757575; line-height:12px; text-decoration:none} .links-phone_number a {color:inherit; text-decoration:none} .im {color:#000!important} --> Hey, can you hear me? play message YOUR ACCOUNT HELP CENTER HELP FORUM To edit your email preferences for voicemail, go to the Email notification settings in your account. Google Inc. 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View CA 94043 USA
```

Trying to pull the text "**Hey, can you hear me?**" from this snippet

Trying to pull out the text in bold and get rid of everything else. The beginning and end of this text should always remain the same. For example the right bookend will always be "play message" while the left bookend will always be indicated by "-->"

Is there a way to use formater or code to pull out the bold text only?

Comment: take a look at regular expressions. regex101.com is quite helpful.

Comment: I've been looking at regex, but unfortunately have no previous experience, and haven't been able to get any of my expressions to work

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Regex is almost certainly what you'll want. You can use Formatter by Zapier > Text > Extract Pattern.

Use the text as input and use this as the pattern: `--> (.*?) play message YOUR`. The result is output as `0` for later steps.

you can see an explanation for those characters here: https://regex101.com/r/7wKjuS/3

Regex is a really powerful tool if you learn to use it!